# Cognito Identity fedration RBAC example for amazon?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am using AWS java script sdk to authenticate via amazon authentication provider. Through given examples, I am able to authorize user in cognito identity fedration for my app for default role.
However, when I tried to use RBAC, unable to authenticate and get Identity ID. I tried following after I saw this blog (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cognito-groups-and-fine-grained-role-based-access-control-2/) but none of these works :

Claim : user_id equals value : amzn1.account.XXXXXXXXXXX Role : MyCustomRole

Claim : www.amazon.com:user_id value amzn1.account.XXXXXXXXXXX Role : MyCustomRole

I get below exception in browser :
**Error: NotAuthorizedException: The ambiguous role mapping rules for: www.amazon.com denied this request.**

Can any one post any example of how to use this with amazon identity provider ?

Also, with cloudtrail can we capture logs of these api calls ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following claims while using the Amazon token.
Claims and values are below:

```
iss: www.amazon.com
aud: App Id
sub: Sub from the LWA token.
```

Cognito [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html) are in update process to capture these details.